# jQuery plot to show as timestamp/time rather than date?

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-plugins, plot, flot

So I have a little problem with jquery plot bar graph with timestamp display. My values are being passed as seconds * 1000 using the 'time' format.

```
var plot = $.plot($("#graph"), data, {
    yaxis: {
        ticks: ticks
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        minTickSize: [1, "second"],
        timeFormat: "%M:%S",
        tickDecimals: 0
    },
    grid: {
        show: true,
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#efefef"
    },
    legend: true,
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: toolTipContent
    }
});
```

It works well and fine up until past 24 hours of time in which it suddenly decides to turn it into a date. As you can see below the top bar (which is actually 122 days long not 4 years) spreads over a date range - which well doesn't make much sense from a timestamp point of view.

[image: The Problem]
.
So what I was really hoping the ticks would look like were this: "100.00:00:00, 150.00:00:00, ...", or "1.06:00, 1.12:00, ..." or "06:30:00, 07:00:00, ..."
Is there a easy hacky way of fixing this or do I need to hackily replace the x-axis ticks without the '*time*' format?

EDIT: It is still acting like this with the newest version of flot(0.8.3)

Comment: Replicating this gives me the correct time format (timeFormat: "%M:%S")

Comment: @HayleyGuillou what version of jquery plot you have?

Comment: I have version 0.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always the problem is something simple and mislooked.

The option for setting the format should be all lowercase - `timeformat` *not* `timeFormat`. Using a custom formatter I could also return the correct 'timestamp' format.

```
tickFormatter: function(val, axis){
    var days = parseInt(moment.utc(val/10).format("DDD")) - 1;
    if(days > 0){
        return days + "." + moment.utc(val/10).format("HH:mm:ss");
    } else {
        return moment.utc(val).format("HH:mm:ss");
    }
},
mode: "time",
minTickSize: [1, "second"]
```

I hope this helps somebody else out.